# what happend when user exceed the limit of mysql db_governor on cloudlinux

Tags: mysql, cpanel

When using db_governor for mysql while using Cloud Linux

what happend when user excced the limit of usage mysql resorces?

does the mysql server says "mysql server has gone away" to his request? or what?

any help?